# Hot reload doesn't work but hot restart works in Android Studio

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I recently started learning Flutter. I started with Visual studio code and everything worked perfectly.

I decided to try Android Studio to check if it is smoother but I am facing an issue with Hot Reload.
When I give hot reload, this is the output.

[image: Hot reload]

It shows that 1 library got reloaded but nothing changes in the emulator. However hot restart works...
[image: Hot Restart]

Can someone explain what is wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I got the answer.
To use hot reload/hot restart, you need to have a stateless or stateful widget with a build method inside it. Hot reload checks for changes in the build function to make the changes. My code didn't have a stateless widget and hence it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clic this icon. I think it will force the hot reload when you change some code

[image]

Comment: That is not what I am looking for...That is the same as hot restart

Comment: Ok =/ 
Did you try to restart your emulator and android sutdio ? Sometimes I have this issue, I restart my emulator (try to wipe its data so you start with a fresh device) x)

Answer (score 0):

have you try to :

File -->> invalidate cache and restart?