# hot reload doesn't work on android emulator using VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, flutter-hotreload

### Hot reload doesn't work at all on android emulator using VS Code even.

- I just made some simple changes like changing appbar title value.
- But only hot restart works on android emulator (using restart debugging)

#### Can some body help please, thanks!

Comment: have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66168900/12838877